# Spring thymeleaf form and capitalization

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, thymeleaf, forms

I have a simple form (registration.html) for entering user data (first/last name, email):

```html
<form action="#" th:action="@{/user/registration}" th:object="${user}" method="post">                  
    <label>First name:</label>
    <input th:field="*{firstName}" name="firstName" value="" required="required"/> 

    <label>Last name:</label>
    <input name="lastName" value="" required="required"/>

    <label>Email:</label>
    <input type="email" name="email" value="" required="required"/>

    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
<form>
```

On submit I would like to take the entered data and display it in another template (result.html) as:

```html
<p th:text="'First name: ' + ${userdto.firstName}" />
<p th:text="'Last name: ' + ${userdto.lastName}" />
<p th:text="'Email: ' + ${userdto.email}" />
```

My controller looks like:

```
@Controller
public class UserDtoController {

    @GetMapping("/user/registration")
    public String showRegistrationForm(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("user", new Userdto());
        return "registration";
    }

    @PostMapping("/user/registration")   
    public String registerUserAccount(@ModelAttribute Userdto userdto) {
       return "result";
    }
}
```

And the corresponding user model is:

```
public class Userdto {

    private String firstName;

    private String lastName;

    private String email;

    // plus standard getters and setters ...
}
```

This works fine as is, but in fact I would like to rename `class Userdto` to `class UserDto` (with a capital letter "D"). If I do rename it, I receive an error when I submit the form:

> SpelEvaluationException: EL1007E: Property or field 'firstName' cannot be found on null

Which as far as I understand means that in the output (result.html), `userdto` is null.

Why is that and how can I work around it?

Comment: After changing your class to `UserDto` how the `(@ModelAttribute Userdto userdto)` in your postmapping looks like? Maybe you refactor also the variable name to `userDto` and not the html

Comment: Can you please update your post with the code that does NOT work?

Comment: I had forgotton to change the variable name userdto to userDto in the html. (result.html). The name in (@ModelAttribute Userdto userdto) does not matter at all it seems.

Comment: Did question must be closed?

Comment: yes should be closed